# Transfer wordpress blog into mysql database

Tags: php, android, mysql, wordpress, flutter

I have an flutter application on which I want my wordpress blogs from my websote. The wordpress is installed on a hosting platform (cpanel) all data of wordpress is on mysql of that cpanel. But however I am unable to understand the data in mysql. In mysql comments, photos, covers are stored in different tables. I can't find a whole blog in a single table or column.

I thought of scraping my blog data directly from website but that doesnt sound very nice. I aslo tried using javascript to store data into seperate mysql database.

is there anyway to get the whole blog into mysql database? End goal is to show the same blog/blogs of some categories in the flutter app.

Answer (score 0):

I was unaware of wordpress rest api from which we can curl all posts data